# Creating multi dimensional arrays, and handeling same key name issues for json_encode

Tags: php, json

I am trying to adhere to an integration requirement of having multiple items with the same key names, including its meta data into a main array to properly json_encode.

I have tried splitting out and joining arrays, array_push. The only workable solution I have is to manually build this part of the json package. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a sample of what I am struggling with:

```
$message_pack["Header"]["Sequence"] = 'TEST1';
$message_pack["Header"]["TC"] = "1";

$message_pack["ItemDetail"]["ItemName"] = "Item1";
$message_pack["ItemDetail"]["ItemCode"] = "123";
$message_pack["ItemDetail"]["Itemname"] = "Item2";
$message_pack["ItemDetail"]["ItemCode"] = "234"; 

$json_msg = json_encode($message_pack);
```

This will obviously only take the last value passed to the matching key name.

I need to adhere to this json format:

```
{
  "Header": {
    "Sequence": "TEST1",
    "TC": "1", 
  },

  "ItemDetail": [{
        "ItemName": "Item1",
        "ItemCode": "123" }

   {    "ItemName": "Item2",
        "ItemCode": "234" }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make "ItemDetail" an array, else you'll overwrite `$message_pack["ItemDetail"]["Itemname"]` and `$message_pack["ItemDetail"]["ItemCode"]`:

```
<?php

$message_pack["Header"]["Sequence"] = 'TEST1';
$message_pack["Header"]["TC"] = "1";
$message_pack["ItemDetail"][] = ["ItemName" => "Item1", 'ItemCode' => 123];
$message_pack["ItemDetail"][] = ["ItemName" => "Item2", 'ItemCode' => 234];

$json_msg = json_encode($message_pack, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo ($json_msg);
```

will output:

```
{
    "Header": {
        "Sequence": "TEST1",
        "TC": "1"
    },
    "ItemDetail": [
        {
            "ItemName": "Item1",
            "ItemCode": 123
        },
        {
            "ItemName": "Item2",
            "ItemCode": 234
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Spot on, damn never knew you can add an array by passing blank blocks like that. Thanks a mil!